# Can McNemar's test be applied to evaluate multiclass models?

Tags: python, classification, statistics, multiclass-classification, model-evaluations

## Full Disclosure:

I did a [semi-cross post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/403668/edit) of this question due to low traffic on Cross Validated. Once I get an answer on any of the two questions, I will link the answer back to the respective other.

---

## tl;dr

For multiclass classifiers, can you apply McNemar's Test to determine, whether two classifiers are significantly different in how they categorize the same data? Or is McNemar limited to 2-class problems?

---

## Detailed Question

I need to determine whether a number of classifiers are pairwise significantly different in their predictions. I found several sources mentioning [McNemar](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247191/machine-learning-model-comparison-doubts-applying-statistical-tests) as suited for this. Example sources:

[example 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247191/machine-learning-model-comparison-doubts-applying-statistical-tests)

[example 2](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/dietterich98approximate.pdf)

However, I am not sure if these sources assumed binary classifiers.

Now I would like to know if I can apply McNemar's test my multiclass case. To illustrate let me give you an example. For that let's generate a bit of random data

```
>>> # number of categories
... k = 4
>>> 
>>> # random data representing the ground truth in k categories
... ground_truth = np.random.randint(0,k,1000)
>>> # random data representing predictions by two different classifiers
... preds1 = np.random.randint(0,k,1000)
>>> preds2 = np.random.randint(0,k,1000)
```

Now, given this data, can I apply McNemar?

```
>>> # binary arrays coding for whether a prediction did match with the ground truth
... results1 = preds1 == ground_truth
>>> results2 = preds2 == ground_truth
>>> 
>>> table = np.bincount(2 * (results1) + (results2), minlength=2*2).reshape(2, 2)
>>> 
>>> print(table)
[[559 186]
 [186  69]]
>>> from statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables import mcnemar
>>> print(mcnemar(table))
pvalue      1.0
statistic   186.0
```

Would the test be applied correctly like this? Or is McNemar limited to 2-class classifiers only?

My classes are imbalanced btw. if that is relevant.

Comment: I am encountering this problem. Have you got an answer?

Comment: @Oswin Yes, I found this then: https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Multiple_Correlated_Proportions-McNemar-Bowker_Test_of_Symmetry.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I found that too, and finally went to McNemar-Browker. @lo tolmencre